# facebook places API change city language

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about the Facebook Places API:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?type=place

Does anyone know how to get the city name in a different language from Facebook?

If I use a locale in the request, then I still get the english version of the city in the location object:
e.g.

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?type=place&limit=10&fields=name,category_list,location,phone,website,city&locale=de_DE&q=Petersdom

city is always "Rome". But with the locale "de_DE" it should be "Rom".

Does anyone have experience with it?

thanks